# Synergy Pro 2 - Works on Macbook Pro, Wont install on Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, macbook-pro, synergy

I've been using Synergy at work for over two years now. I have a Macbook Pro and a Windows 7 laptop. I am unable to complete the installation of Synergy 2 pro on my windows 7 laptop. It gets about 70% through the setup and then gives me the following error:

Service 'Synergy' (Synergy) failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.

My account is an administrator and I clicked "yes" to allow this program to make changes at the start of the install. There is no reason for this application to need additional privileges to finish the installation that I can see.

I tried to install Revo Uninstaller as suggested in another thread, but Synergy doesn't come up as a program that I can even uninstall. I tried deleting the folder in C:/program files and searching & deleting anything else related. Nothing has helped. I get the same error every time I re-install.

Currently I cannot use my Windows 7 laptop at work now because I cannot download the old version again that was working. I'm dead in the water here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue myself by letting Windows updates run all night. I had about 46 updates to install. I was able to install Synergy Pro 2 without any issues this morning. It's working great too.